# Exchanging/Passing Values between C# forms

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code. Its working fine and there is no error but a logical one i think so. I have used a method PassValue(int id) to get value from another from. I have tested it and the forms are exchanging the values correctly but the problem comes when I use the value which i have received from other form as a "textbox.text" or a "label.text"

Here is my code:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
public partial class UserProfile : Form
{
    public string empidstr;
    public UserProfile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
    public void PassValue(int id)
    {

        string idstring = Convert.ToString(id);
       // empidlabel.Text = idstring;
        empidstr = idstring;
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        empidlabel.Text = empidstr;
    }

    private void UserProfile_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }  
}}
```

Comment: What problem you face?

Comment: Where is PassValue() being called? If the user clicks button before it's called then empidstr will be empty.

Comment: What kind of issue do you have ?

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line empidstr = idstring; to check that it is actually happening before you click button 2.